# Dictionary with compound key that's not defined at compile time

Tags: .net, data-structures

I'm writing a function that will take some kind of input data structure (probably a DataTable; it's still up in the air, but the important part is that its structure won't be defined until run-time) and split one of its string columns into lists of tokens. The end result will be some data structure (possibly a Dictionary, but again, it's still up in the air) that will allow fast retrieval of these lists of tokens based on the primary key from the original data structure.

Typically you would use a Tuple for a compound key, but since this is meant to be a tool that will connect to a database and fetch arbitrary tables/queries, I can't take that approach here. Is there something suitable for doing this that's built in to .NET before I go writing my own CompoundKey class to handle this? It's something that's going to come up in several places in this application, not just this particular tokenizing function.

Here's a very rough idea of what the method would look like, with "object" standing in for whatever compound key class ends up being used. Note that the `CompoundKey` class doesn't actually exist (yet), and WordBreakChars would be either `string[]` or `char[]`, prepared elsewhere in the class.

```
public Dictionary<object, string[]> SplitTokens(DataTable table, string split_column) {
    Dictionary<object, string[]> Results = new Dictionary<object, string[]>();
    DataColumn[] KeyCols = table.PrimaryKey;
    if (KeyCols == null || KeyCols.Length == 0) {
        throw new ArgumentException("DataTable has no primary key.");
    }

    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows) {
        string[] tokens = (row[split_column] as string ?? "").Split(WordBreakChars, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        CompoundKey key = new CompoundKey();
        foreach (DataColumn col in KeyCols) {
            key.Add(col.ColumnName, row[col]);
            Results.Add(key, tokens);
        }
    }

    return Results;
}
```

Comment: Well, use object.  Whatever actual object you use at runtime needs to implement GetHashCode() and Equals() properly.  How you do this is completely up to you.

Comment: @HansPassant Yeah, I'm probably going to end up wrapping/extending Dictionary and giving it a few tweaks to make it more suitable for equality comparison. Just don't want to do that if .NET already provides an elegant and highly tested solution here. Time to pull out ILSpy and take a stroll through Dictionary to see how it implements GetHashCode() and Equals() out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

In situations like this I would make a generic function with a "Key selector". In fact, LINQ already provides this in one of it's overloads of `.ToDictionary(` you can use that in combination with your existing code to greatly simplify the method

```
public Dictionary<T, string[]> SplitTokens<T>(DataTable table, string split_column, Func<DataRow, T> keySelector)
{
    Dictionary<T, string[]> Results;

    Results = table.AsEnumerable().ToDictionary(keySelector, 
              row => (row[split_column] as string ?? "").Split(WordBreakChars, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));

    return Results;
}
```

Now the caller can pass whatever they want in to `keySelector` and that will be the strongly typed datatype for the resultant dictionary.

Comment: I like it, but it seems like there will still be a compile-time requirement to know the type/structure of the key *somewhere*. It's just that now it's in whatever is calling `SplitTokens()`. In this application, the type of the key will not be known until run-time, as it will be derived from whatever user-selected table/query is eventually getting passed in for tokenization.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't particularly fancy, but it seems like it'll do the job.

```
public class CompoundKey : IEquatable<CompoundKey>, IEnumerable {
    private object[] _Key;
    private int _Hash;
    private bool _Hashed;

    //Dictionary keys need to be immutable. DO NOT expect sane behavior if you modify items inside the key.
    public object this[int index] {
        get { return _Key[index]; }
    }

    public CompoundKey(params object[] Key) {
        _Key = Key;
        _Hashed = false;
    }

    public static implicit operator CompoundKey(object[] Key) {
        return new CompoundKey(Key);
    }

    public int Length { get { return _Key.Length; } }

    public override int GetHashCode() {
        if (!_Hashed) {
            _Hash = 0;
            foreach (object o in _Key) {
                if (o != null) {
                    _Hash ^= o.GetHashCode();
                }
            }
        }
        return _Hash;
    }

    public bool Equals(CompoundKey other) {
        if (other.GetHashCode() != _Hash) {
            return false;
        }
        if (other.Length != this.Length) {
            return false;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < this.Length; i++) {
            if (other[i] != this[i]) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj) {
        if (!(obj is CompoundKey)) {
            return false;
        }
        return this.Equals((CompoundKey)obj);
    }

    public static bool operator ==(CompoundKey a, CompoundKey b) {
        if ((object)a == null || (object)b == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return a.Equals(b);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(CompoundKey a, CompoundKey b) {
        return !(a == b);
    }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator() {
        return _Key.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

I added the implicit cast from `object[]`, so usage can be simplified as feeding an `object[]` directly into the dictionary. (I know I can Linq away the inner for loop that builds the key array with `.Select()`; I just made it a bit more explicit for now for easier debugging.)

```
    public Dictionary<CompoundKey, string[]> SplitTokens(DataTable table, string split_column) {
        Dictionary<CompoundKey, string[]> Results = new Dictionary<CompoundKey, string[]>();
        DataColumn[] key = table.PrimaryKey;
        Regex RemoveIgnoredCharacters = new Regex("[" + Regex.Escape(Ignore) + "]");

        char[] WordBreakChars = WordBreak.ToCharArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++) {
            string split_value = RemoveIgnoredCharacters.Replace(table.Rows[i][split_column] as string ?? "", "");
            string[] tokens = split_value.Split(WordBreakChars, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            object[] dictkey = new object[key.Length];
            for (int j = 0; j < key.Length; j++) {
                dictkey[j] = table.Rows[i][key[j].ColumnName];
            }
            Results.Add(dictkey, tokens);
        }

        return Results;
    }
```